# How to add a Button to the li tag dynamically using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am creating a Button dynamically and need to add to the li tag

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/1ty1v8u1/7/

[image]

This is my code

```
function showRestaurantDetailsByLocation(response,locationname)
{
$('.restListings').remove();
$('.addNewRestaurant').remove();
var ulhtml = $('<ul class="restListings"></ul>');
var divhtml = $('<div class="inner-intit"><sub class="sub">Your Favorite Area</sub></div>');
divhtml.append('<br>');
var $newbutton= $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', location:locationname , name:'btn1', class:'btn btn-success', value:'Add For'+locationname});
var $ordernow= $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button',name:'btn1', class:'btn btn-success', value:'Order Now'});
for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
{
divhtml.append('<li><h6>'+response[i].area+'</h6><p>'+response[i].address+'</p></li>');
}
divhtml.append($newbutton); 
divhtml.append($ordernow); 
ulhtml.append(divhtml);
$("#"+locationname).append(ulhtml);
}
```

I tried with these options

```
var $ordernow= $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button',  name:'btn2', class:'btn btn-success ordernow', value:'Order Now'});

divhtml.append('<li class="innerChild" user_location="'+locationname+'" vendor_name="'+response[i].vendor_name+'"    vendor_id="'+response[i].vendor_id+'" ><h6> '+response[i].vendor_name+'</h6><p>'+response[i].locality+' , '+response[i].area+' </p><p><b>Timings:</b> '+response[i].start_time+' - '+response[i].end_time+'</p><span class="inDeleteInnerSub"></span></li>');

$('<li />').appendTo(ordernow);
```

Approach 2 :

```
divhtml.append('<li class="innerChild" user_location="'+locationname+'" vendor_name="'+response[i].vendor_name+'"    vendor_id="'+response[i].vendor_id+'" ><h6> '+response[i].vendor_name+'</h6><p>'+response[i].locality+' , '+response[i].area+' </p><p><b>Timings:</b> '+response[i].start_time+' - '+response[i].end_time+'</p><span class="inDeleteInnerSub"></span>ordernow </li>');
```

Approach 3 :

```
divhtml.append('<li class="innerChild" user_location="'+locationname+'" vendor_name="'+response[i].vendor_name+'"    vendor_id="'+response[i].vendor_id+'" ><h6> '+response[i].vendor_name+'</h6><p>'+response[i].locality+' , '+response[i].area+' </p><p><b>Timings:</b> '+response[i].start_time+' - '+response[i].end_time+'</p><span class="inDeleteInnerSub"></span>'+$ordernow+'</li>');
```

With this its being shown as **Object Object**

Comment: a little more effort is needed to explain your issue. You haven't provided an explanation of a problem or the expected behavior and question in subject is the only question asked and it is very vague.

Comment: Well its not i didn't tried , i tried locally and dont want to put the code which isn'tworking . anyway i will update my question with the things i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want your "Order now" button inside the li element change the following lines:

Original:

```
divhtml.append($ordernow);
```

Modified:

```
divhtml.children("li").append($ordernow);
```

Additionally, if you want your button appear on the right side just add this css-property to the button:

```
float:right
```

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvx4tkLt/).

**EDIT:**

Or even closer to your picture is this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7Lbav5y/). I added a container-div for the h6 and p with a css-property of

```
float:left
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , this was a ton help to me .